# Erro ao carregar projeto JSF: URL alterando sozinha

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, jsf-2.2

Ao executar meu projeto no netbeans, o meu projeto esta sendo carregado na URL `http://localhost:8080/loogix//` quando, na verdade, deveria carregar `http://localhost:8080/loogix/faces/index.xhtml`.

O Log ao executar é:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9009
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
nov 30, 2017 11:14:35 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFORMAÇÕES: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
nov 30, 2017 11:14:35 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
ADVERTÊNCIA: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
nov 30, 2017 11:14:35 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
ADVERTÊNCIA: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@7cec179 in service registry.
Found populator: com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.GFDomainXml
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\lib\templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\lib\templates\logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=C:\Users\thiag\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\config\GF_4.1\domain1\config\logging.properties
Informações:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)
Informações:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Informações:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Informações:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Informações:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Informações:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Informações:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Grave:   Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/C:/Users/thiag/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Banco/target/Banco-1.0/
Grave:   Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/C:/Users/thiag/Documents/NetBeansProjects/produto/target/produto-1.0/
Informações:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 28ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Informações:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Informações:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
Informações:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   Java security manager is disabled.
Informações:   Entering Security Startup Service.
Informações:   Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
Informações:   Security Service(s) started successfully.
Informações:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
Informações:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
Informações:   Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
Informações:   Created virtual server server
Informações:   Created virtual server __asadmin
Informações:   Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
Informações:   Virtual server server loaded default web module 
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
Informações:   Portable JNDI names for EJB FornecedorExternoDAO: [java:global/loogix/FornecedorExternoDAO, java:global/loogix/FornecedorExternoDAO!br.com.loogix.dao.FornecedorExternoDAO]
Informações:   Portable JNDI names for EJB FuncaoDAO: [java:global/loogix/FuncaoDAO!br.com.loogix.dao.FuncaoDAO, java:global/loogix/FuncaoDAO]
Informações:   Portable JNDI names for EJB AlmoxarifadoDAO: [java:global/loogix/AlmoxarifadoDAO!br.com.loogix.dao.AlmoxarifadoDAO, java:global/loogix/AlmoxarifadoDAO]
Informações:   Portable JNDI names for EJB SaidaDAO: [java:global/loogix/SaidaDAO, java:global/loogix/SaidaDAO!br.com.loogix.dao.SaidaDAO]
Informações:   Portable JNDI names for EJB UsuarioDAO: [java:global/loogix/UsuarioDAO, java:global/loogix/UsuarioDAO!br.com.loogix.dao.UsuarioDAO]
Informações:   Portable JNDI names for EJB ProdutoAlmoxarifadoDAO: [java:global/loogix/ProdutoAlmoxarifadoDAO!br.com.loogix.dao.ProdutoAlmoxarifadoDAO, java:global/loogix/ProdutoAlmoxarifadoDAO]
Informações:   Portable JNDI names for EJB EmpregadoDAO: [java:global/loogix/EmpregadoDAO, java:global/loogix/EmpregadoDAO!br.com.loogix.dao.EmpregadoDAO]
Informações:   Portable JNDI names for EJB EntradaDAO: [java:global/loogix/EntradaDAO!br.com.loogix.dao.EntradaDAO, java:global/loogix/EntradaDAO]
Informações:   Portable JNDI names for EJB ProdutoDAO: [java:global/loogix/ProdutoDAO!br.com.loogix.dao.ProdutoDAO, java:global/loogix/ProdutoDAO]
Informações:   WELD-000900: 2.2.2 (Final)
WARN:   WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PostActivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
WARN:   WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PrePassivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
Informações:   Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) para o contexto '/loogix'
Informações:   Running on PrimeFaces 5.0
Informações:   Loading application [loogix] at [/loogix]
Informações:   Loading application loogix done in 8.895 ms
Informações:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (13) startup time : Felix (1.958ms), startup services(9.586ms), total(11.544ms)
Informações:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
Informações:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://AIMBRA-002:8686/jndi/rmi://AIMBRA-002:8686/jmxrmi
Informações:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
Informações:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 16ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Informações:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
Informações:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 14ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Informações:   Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.10.4 2014-08-08 15:09:00...
Informações:   Listening to REST requests at context: /management/domain.
Informações:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@25cd49a4 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@54f4a7f0.
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) para o contexto ''
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
Informações:   Loading application [__admingui] at [/]
Informações:   Loading application __admingui done in 4.486 ms
Informações:   file:/C:/Users/thiag/Documents/NetBeansProjects/loogix/target/loogix-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/_com.loogix_loogix_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU login successful
Informações:   Portable JNDI names for EJB SaidaDAO: [java:global/loogix/SaidaDAO, java:global/loogix/SaidaDAO!br.com.loogix.dao.SaidaDAO]
Informações:   Portable JNDI names for EJB EntradaDAO: [java:global/loogix/EntradaDAO!br.com.loogix.dao.EntradaDAO, java:global/loogix/EntradaDAO]
Informações:   Portable JNDI names for EJB ProdutoAlmoxarifadoDAO: [java:global/loogix/ProdutoAlmoxarifadoDAO!br.com.loogix.dao.ProdutoAlmoxarifadoDAO, java:global/loogix/ProdutoAlmoxarifadoDAO]
Informações:   Portable JNDI names for EJB ProdutoDAO: [java:global/loogix/ProdutoDAO!br.com.loogix.dao.ProdutoDAO, java:global/loogix/ProdutoDAO]
Informações:   Portable JNDI names for EJB FuncaoDAO: [java:global/loogix/FuncaoDAO!br.com.loogix.dao.FuncaoDAO, java:global/loogix/FuncaoDAO]
Informações:   Portable JNDI names for EJB FornecedorExternoDAO: [java:global/loogix/FornecedorExternoDAO, java:global/loogix/FornecedorExternoDAO!br.com.loogix.dao.FornecedorExternoDAO]
Informações:   Portable JNDI names for EJB EmpregadoDAO: [java:global/loogix/EmpregadoDAO, java:global/loogix/EmpregadoDAO!br.com.loogix.dao.EmpregadoDAO]
Informações:   Portable JNDI names for EJB UsuarioDAO: [java:global/loogix/UsuarioDAO, java:global/loogix/UsuarioDAO!br.com.loogix.dao.UsuarioDAO]
Informações:   Portable JNDI names for EJB AlmoxarifadoDAO: [java:global/loogix/AlmoxarifadoDAO!br.com.loogix.dao.AlmoxarifadoDAO, java:global/loogix/AlmoxarifadoDAO]
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
Informações:   Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) para o contexto '/loogix'
Informações:   Running on PrimeFaces 5.0
Informações:   Loading application [loogix] at [/loogix]
Informações:   loogix was successfully deployed in 4.236 milliseconds.
```

Comment: Posta o web.xml por favor

Answer (score -1):

Não trabalho com NetBeans por isso não sei exatamente onde mexer, mas acredito que ele tenha algo referenciando o **context root** do seu projeto. O **context root** é a *url home* da sua aplicação.

Você pode verificar também as configurações do seu servidor. Em algum lugar há essa possibilidade de configuração de **URL**, permitindo você mudar de *http://localhost:8080/loogix//* por *http://localhost:8080/loogix/faces/index.xhtml*